# How can I use medium widget in a React website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I found one of amazing link [Here](https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io) that create widget for the `Medium` posts.

Unfortunately I could not use the code in a `react` website

example(A random medium author):

```
<div id="medium-widget"></div>
    <script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js"></script>
    <script>MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/@sunilsandhu","postsPerLine":2,"limit":4,"picture":"big","fields":["description","author","claps","publishAt"],"ratio":"landscape"}})</script>
```

Result is should be like this

[image]

How can I use the code in React website ?

Also I found a Angular version of this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-medium-posts-widget)
but could not use in React app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In index.html

```
<script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mediumWidget(){
    MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/@sunilsandhu","postsPerLine":2,"limit":4,"picture":"big","fields":["description","author","claps","publishAt"],"ratio":"landscape"}});
  }
</script>
```

In your component

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.mediumWidget();
}
render() {
  return (<div id="medium-widget"></div>);
}
```

Comment: When I use componentWillMount() I got an error and I change to `Did` which is working now. Thank you. Also why I needed it to change

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I'm a bit tired. So you need to call the function after the component is mounted, because if you do it before, the `<div id="medium-widget"/>` is not yet existing in the dom. And the widget have not place to appear

Comment: Seems like https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/ is not available anymore. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

just run the `MediumWidget.Init` code at `componentDidMount` life cycle or use the `useEffect` hook to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in your index.html

```html
<script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function mediumWidget() {
          MediumWidget.Init({
            renderTo: "#medium-widget",
            params: {
              resource: "https://medium.com/@sunilsandhu",
              postsPerLine: 2,
              limit: 4,
              picture: "big",
              fields: ["description", "author", "claps", "publishAt"],
              ratio: "landscape",
            },
          });
        }
        
      </script>
```

Add the following code in your component.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        try {
          
          var widget = document.getElementById("medium-widget");
          if (!!widget) {
            window.mediumWidget();
          }
        }
        catch(e){
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }
    return (<div id="medium-widget" ></div>)
```

If you have multiple pages in your react application and if you use history.push() for each page then when you come back the page which renders medium widget gives an error.

Therefore I add try-catch. we need to check whether the medium widget load or not. If the medium fails to load the page will reload again.

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the code a little and found a method to use to unmount the widget.  The result:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    window.MediumWidget.Init(widgetParams);
    return () => {
      window.MediumWidget.unmount();
    };
  }, []);
```

The `unmount()` method can also be called in `ComponentWillUnmount` if yer into that.